# Testing and accessing values in tuples within lists?

Tags: python

I'm doing some exercises on list comprehensions and in this one the y coordinate needs to be limited to 0<=y<=10, I know this doesn't work at all but I can't get my head round tuples within lists and how to access the second part of the tuple in order to test it

```
  xvals = [x for x in range(-5,5)]
  yvals = [(x**2)+5 for x in xvals]
  coords = list(zip(xvals, yvals))
  limitedcoords = [i for i in coords if ((j in i) <= 10)]
  print(limitedcoords)
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: `limitedcoords = [(x,y) for x,y in coords if y <= 10)]`

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `filter()` in combination with a `lambda` function:

```
xvals = [x for x in range(-5,5)]
yvals = [(x**2)+5 for x in xvals]
coords = list(zip(xvals, yvals))

print(coords)

limitedcoords = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] <= 10, coords))
print(limitedcoords)
```

This yields

```
[(-5, 30), (-4, 21), (-3, 14), (-2, 9), (-1, 6), (0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 9), (3, 14), (4, 21)]
[(-2, 9), (-1, 6), (0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 9)]
```

Here, `coords` are filtered on the second coordinate `x[1]`.

---

An alternative would be

```
limitedcoords = [(x,y) for x,y in coords if 0 <= y <= 10]
print(limitedcoords)
```

Which yields the same result and is potentially faster.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the y and bounding it between `0` and `10` can be achieved as follows:

```
limitedcoords = [(x, min(max(0, y), 10)) for x, y in coords]
```

which produces:

```
[(-5, 10), (-4, 10), (-3, 10), (-2, 9), (-1, 6), (0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 9), (3, 10), (4, 10)]
```

without the `min(max(0, y), 10)` part, you would get:

```
[(-5, 30), (-4, 21), (-3, 14), (-2, 9), (-1, 6), (0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 9), (3, 14), (4, 21)]
```

---

Notice how the `30` y-coord of the first tuple becomes `10` and so on. Finally, using `0` as a lower bound does not make sense since this is already covered by *math* (`x**2` cannot be `<0` if we are talking *real numbers*) so there is no need to check for that.

---

How the `min(max(0, y), 10)` works:

Reading it from the inside out, we are actually saying:

1. take the `max` of `0` and `y` (let's call this `temp`)
2. take the `min` of `temp` and `10`.

## Examples in pseudocode:

```
y = -10
max(y, 0) -> 0
min(0, 10) -> 0
answer = 0  # -10 becomes 0

y = 3
max(y, 0) -> 3
min(3, 10) -> 3
answer = 3  # 3 becomes 3

y = 20
max(y, 0) -> 20
min(20, 10) -> 10
answer = 10  # 20 becomes 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a stylistic + performance point. [Please see solutions by [@Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49111510/9209546) / [@Ev.Kounis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49111562/9209546) for details on fixing your algorithm.]

The benefit of functionality such as `range()`, `zip()` and generator expression denoted by comprehensions within `()` is that they are all lazy. For efficiency, it is often optimal to be lazy until calculations are actually required.

Here is an example of how you can rewrite your algorithm with this in mind:

```
xvals = range(-5, 5)
yvals = ((x**2)+5 for x in xvals)
coords = zip(xvals, yvals)

limitedcoords = [(x, y) for x, y in coords if y <= 10]
# [(-2, 9), (-1, 6), (0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 9)]
```